# RSS feed interative retrieval

Tags: rss

Does RSS feeds provides any way for iterative retrieval like first retrieve some N number of items and in next request retrieve next N number of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSS feeds are just XML files and can include any number of elements your server decides to include in it.

You could write a server to process requests from a client so that it returns the next set of N items on each request. But you'd have to program the server and the client so that they know how to speak to each other. It wouldn't be too hard to include the last item received in your request, so that the server would know where to start with the next item.